# how to append a character randomly to a string?

Tags: c, random, char, concatenation

I am trying to generate a string which concatenates a character to a given string.

for example, my string is "hello" and the character is '#'. I want to generate a string which shows all the possible combinations of these. ie, the results can be "hello#","he#llo","hell#o" etc..

can you provide the code to generate such a string using C ?

Thank you for the effort.

Comment: Have you started trying to break down the problem? What pattern do you notice in all possible combinations, when listed?

Comment: @ArunG: how would you write this code? What have you tried?

Comment: You are expected to show a bit of your own effort first, that's how this site works.

Answer (score 1):

You need some help with the algorithm.

Say the string is pointed to by a pointer *s*, `char *s = "hello";`.

To determine the random position, you can use `rand()` from the *stdlib* library. In C, arrays (a string is an array of chars, or is pointed to by a char pointer (and ends with the 0-byte). In each case *arr[0]* or *ptr[0]* is the first char) first index is 0. Thus the last char is at [length-1]. To ensure the random position is between 0 and length-1, you can use the modulo `%` operator, eg `int position = rand() % strlen(s);`, but since the random char may be at the end, you need to add 1 to that `strlen(s)`.

- determine the position as above
- create a char array of length is length(s)+2  (random char & ending 0 are added) named *t*
- copy the `s` part from 0 to `position-1` (beware of the `position == 0` case) into *t* (eg *strncpy*)
- concat to *t* the random char (say *t* is a string of 1 char, that'd be easier, while there is a trick to copy easily just one char...) (eg *strcat*)
- concat to *t* the remaining part of *s* i.e. from *position* (beware of `position == length(s)` case)

  - display *t*
- repeat *ad nauseum*

Don't know if it is an assignment or something you want to do by yourself - none of my business. But just give it a try - by yourself. You'll see. At first, it's a PITA. Then it's  a lot of fun!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_combinations(char *some_string,char some_char)
{
   char *new_string = malloc(strlen(some_string) + 2);
   for (unsigned long j = 0; j < (strlen(some_string) + 1); j++)
   {
      unsigned long i = 0;
      unsigned long k = 0;
      for (; i < (strlen(some_string) + 1); i++)
      {
         if (i == j)
         {
            new_string[i] = some_char;
         }
         else
         {
            new_string[i] = some_string[k];
            k++;
         }
      }
      new_string[i] = '\0';
      printf("pattern %lu: %s\n",j+1,new_string); 
   } 
   free(new_string);
}


int main(void)
{
   print_combinations("hello",'#');
}
```

output:

```
pattern 1: #hello    
pattern 2: h#ello    
pattern 3: he#llo    
pattern 4: hel#lo    
pattern 5: hell#o         
pattern 6: hello#
```

Answer (score 0):

Here after an idea about how your algorithm looks.

```
char *base_string = "hello";

string  = calloc(1,sizeof(char)); 

repeat loop (from i = 0 to length of base_string) { 

    string = realloc(old size of string + sizeof(base_string) +2) // +2 : 1 for null terminate string and 1 for #

    new_insert_position_in_string = string + i * (sizeof(base_string) +1);

    reapeat loop (from j = 0 to j< (length of  base_string )) {
        if (j==i) then {
            new_insert_position_in_string[j] = '#';
            new_insert_position_in_string++;
            continue;
        }
        new_insert_position_in_string[j] = base_string[j];
    }
    new_insert_position_in_string[length of  base_string + 1] = '#';

}
```

And now it's up to you to deduce the C code